# We need to confirm that your request is Valid .Please repeat your last action

Tags: javascript

Currently we have a custom button named Request Bid/No bid approval which gets activated via onclick Javascript. due to winter release 16 we are no more able to process any approval in salesforce.

Screenshot is attached for your reference.Custome Button with Details

[image]

Your input will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Hareesh

Answer (score 1):

As per winter 16 release the use of REQUIRESCRIPT will create problems and will not load JavaScript on page load and would recommend to convert all logic in JavaScript button to a single visualforce page actions .

Please see the below article

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_requirescript.htm